# ¿Cómo hacer un simple ejemplo de un editor de html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo que pretendo es hacer un simple editor en un `<textarea>`, aunque sea solo reconocer el tag `<p>` y que cambie el color de este "tag" a rojo.

Solamente pretendo ver un sencillo ejemplo reconociendo ese "tag", gracias de antemano por cualquier respuesta.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que con determinadas palabras reservadas el texto tenga determinados comportamientos?

Comment: Si, algo así. Por ejemplo que reconozca esta simple línea de código: `<h1>Hola mundo!</h1>` y solamente lo que es el tag `<h1>` le de un color rojo. No se si me explico....

Comment: Una vez respondí algo similar, puedes verlo en el siguiente [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40250/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-el-efecto-de-escritura-din%C3%A1mico), [Link de la respuesta](https://jsfiddle.net/arie_cwhat/xe03tcww/). Usando un código Javascript quizá puedas detectar y formatear el contenido de tu contenedor de texto. Adicionalmente creo que un <textarea> no te serviría de mucho, inspecciona el código de Stackoverflow y fijate que para mostrar el codigo de los usuarios usan etiquetas span es su mayoría

Comment: No es eso exactamente lo que pretendo, es más bien algo que analice la sintaxis de un texto, es decir lo que es un editor HTML para programar, pero solo pretendo por ejemplo que reconozca la sintaxis de por ejemplo el TAG <h1>hola</h1> y que cambie el color del TAG <h1> a color rojo, y el color del texto "hola" a gris. ¿Me explico?

Comment: ¿buscas hacer algo [así](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/h5c4edrd/)? (Click en el espacio blanco y escribe algo como `<h1>hola</h1>`)

Comment: Podrías usar `contenteditable` pero la respuesta no sería tan sencilla como parece (especialmente si quieres que se haga de forma dinámica), haría falta analizar el código cada vez que se cambie, procesarlo y comprobar si se ha añadido (o borrado) alguna etiqueta para actuar en consecuencia.